# How to search and modify one nucleotide within a gene sequence using python?

Tags: python

I hope this question isn't redundant. I'm trying to write a script that can search and modify any single nucleotide within a gene sequence. I've looked into using arrays and motifs but I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm really new at programming so i'm still learning. Any help is appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict
import re, sys, random

# - - - - - H E A D E R - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
'''
Objectives:
1. Read in a sequence
2. Find a specific segment of that sequence
3. Change a letter (mutation)
4. Output the sequence with the mutation

'''

# - - - - - U S E R    V A R I A B L E S - - - - - - - -

mssg = " Search and Destroy"
genFile  = 'P1.txt'
inFile   = 'P1.txt'
inFolder = '.'
site   = ""  # what the mutation is 
outFile  = "Project1-Out.txt"
GenSeqs = defaultdict(lambda: "my own unknown" )
#- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# - - - - - M A I N - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

print("\n\n", mssg, ". . . . ")


# Task 1: Open a file and read the sequences
IN1 = open( "P1.txt", 'r')
number = 1
for line in IN1:
    if (re.match('>', line)):
        header = line.rstrip()   # remove right white space
    else:
        GenSeqs[header] = line.rstrip()   # Dict[key] = value, key = header, value = sequence
        number += 0

print("There are %d gene sequences in file %s" % (number, inFile))
```

Here is the input file for this task:

> reverse translation of sp|P68871|HBB_HUMAN Hemoglobin subunit beta OS=Homo sapiens GN=HBB PE=1 SV=2 to a 441 base sequence of most likely codons.
>   atggtgcatctgaccccggaagaaaaaagcgcggtgaccgcgctgtggggcaaagtgaac
>   gtggatgaagtgggcggcgaagcgctgggccgcctgctggtggtgtatccgtggacccag
>   cgcttttttgaaagctttggcgatctgagcaccccggatgcggtgatgggcaacccgaaa
>   gtgaaagcgcatggcaaaaaagtgctgggcgcgtttagcgatggcctggcgcatctggat
>   aacctgaaaggcacctttgcgaccctgagcgaactgcattgcgataaactgcatgtggat
>   ccggaaaactttcgcctgctgggcaacgtgctggtgtgcgtgctggcgcatcattttggc
>   aaagaatttaccccgccggtgcaggcggcgtatcagaaagtggtggcgggcgtggcgaac
>   gcgctggcgcataaatatcat

Comment: Can you add the structure and contents of an example input file?

Comment: @VasilisG. It looks like FASTA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format. But Moks, you don't seem to have any clear criteria on why nucleotide to change. You can use BioPython for manipulating these kind of files easily BTW

Comment: The input file is in a FASTA format. The nucleotide change is to essentially simulate how a gene sequence can be affected by SNPs (single nucleotide polymorphisms). I want to make these mutations, then output the file.

Comment: Also, thank you for suggesting BioPython! I'm downloading it now.

Comment: @VasilisG Here's a sample:                                                           
 >reverse translation of sp|P68871|HBB_HUMAN Hemoglobin subunit beta OS=Homo sapiens GN=HBB PE=1 SV=2 to a 441 base sequence of most likely codons.
atggtgcatctgaccccggaagaaaaaagcgcggtgaccgcgctgtggggcaaagtgaac
gtggatgaagtgggcggcgaagcgctgggccgcctgctggtggtgtatccgtggacccag
gtgaaagcgcatggcaaaaaagtgctgggcgcgtttagcgatggcctggcgcatctggat
aacctgaaaggcacctttgcgaccctgagcgaactgcattgcgataaactgcatgtggatccggaaaactttcgcctgctgggcaacgtgctggtgtgcgtgctggcgcatcattttggc
aaagaatttaccccgccggtgcaggcggcgtatcagaaagtggtggcgggcgtggc

Comment: @Moks good, but you should probably edit your question and add it there as part of it, rather than posting it in the comment section.

Comment: Good point, thanks!